# Problem with loading VBA add-in on friends computer

Tags: excel, vba

The add-in works when it is on my computer however once I emailed both the add in file and macro enabled file the add in no longer worked and it said cannot open two files with the same name at the same time.I don't understand why he is getting this error message. The add in on my friends computer seems to load up the sheet with the VBA on it but it doesn't do it on mine, might this be the problem and why does it do that?

For context this is a macro which filters accounts and highlights certain fields. I load in an excel file which I get sent everyday, therefore I wanted to add a button in the quick access toolbar to run the macro.

My process was I emailed both the files. Then saved them to his computer. Went to developer, excel add-ins, found the file, added it, then assigned it to the quick access toolbar. Did I miss something?

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "modified_report" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("modified_report").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next
End Sub

'Copying sheet

Sub copy_sheet()
Sheets("fed_instr_extract_revised").Select
Excel.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Excel.Sheets("fed_instr_extract_revised")

'Rename new copied sheet

Excel.ActiveSheet.Name = "modified_report"
End Sub

'filtering equity accounts

Sub filter_equity()

Set ws = Worksheets("modified_report")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("modified_report").Select

'Selecting the equity accounts


Selection.AutoFilter
    Worksheets("modified_report").Range("$A$1:$A$2000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "106", "123", "323", "217", "290", "291", "390", "590", "790", "792", "793", "890"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub

'deleting equity accounts

    Sub delete_equity()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

'deleting the autofiltered equity accounts

    Set sh = Sheets("modified_report")
    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

'selecting previous accounts

Sub filter_by_acr()

Set ws = Worksheets("modified_report")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strInput = InputBox("Enter acronym to filter on")

    Worksheets("modified_report").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=strInput

End Sub


'deleting filter accounts

Sub delete_filtered_acr()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("modified_report")
    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub


'filter for everything but the accounts from this month
Sub filtering_older_than_one_month()
Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("modified_report")

Selection.AutoFilter
    Worksheets("modified_report").Range("$A$1:$A$2000").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Date - 3)
End Sub

'deleting 1 month old accounts
Sub delete_filtered_date()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("modified_report")
    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub



'highlighting

Sub highlight()
    Dim myRange As Range, cel As Range
    Set myRange = Sheets("modified_report").Range("K:M")
    n = Sheets("modified_report").Range("K" & Sheets("modified_report").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cel In myRange
      If cel.Row > n Then Exit For
      If Trim(cel.Value) = "" Then cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Next cel
End Sub





'sort highlighted

Sub sort_highlighted()
    Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("modified_report").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("modified_report").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "K2:K255"), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("modified_report").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "L2:L255"), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("modified_report").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "M2:M255"), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("modified_report").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:Q255")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

For the macro to run the same as it does on my computer.

Comment: Make sure the add-in is in Excel's add-in folder and nowhere else. Then make sure that the buttons are assigned to the add-in in that folder and not the downloaded add-in. Otherwise Excel loads the add-in from the default add-in folder and if you press a button it tries to open the same filename from the other folder (and fails).

Comment: Did you send the files as attachments? Many email virus scanners messes with macro enabled workbooks. Zipping them is often the simplest workaround

Comment: @Sam while this is true it cannot be the issue that results in *"cannot open two files with the same name at the same time"*

Comment: True! That would take some messed up virus scanner

Comment: @PeH thanks, so I must save the add in file to excel add-ins folder. Does it matter where I save the macro enabled excel file?

Comment: @jhill no, just make sure the add-in file exists only in the add-in folder and no where else on the computer. Then link the buttons to that add-in file.